# изменении разрешение текста

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении разрешения изменялся размер текста - Status server ?

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `@media screen`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

И так далее...

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку, я не могу оставлять коментарии из-за рейтинговой системы, то создам ответ, основаный на предвдущем.

> Используйте @media screen

Однако, рекоммендую использовать их таким образом:

```
body{
  font-size:100%;
}

p {
 font-size: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 p {
 font-size:1.2em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 p {
 font-size:2em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 p{
 font-size:2.5em;
 }
}
```

[ссылка на работающий пример](https://codepen.io/LostAndForgotten/pen/LJmEbL?editors=1100)

Поскольку сама долго искала пвпервые ответ на этот вопрос, решила дать его в полной форме, чтоб не оставалось вопросов.